# Entity Framework 6 and explicit loading a graph of objects

Tags: frameworks, linq-to-entities, entity, loading

I have this model structure :

```
public class Blog
{
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{

}
```

I would like to **explicitly load** "Posts" and "Comments" collections.

I **can not use** lazy loading nor eager loading (using Include operator) because my loaded collections **have to be filtered** before loaded into each object (as they may contain huge amount of items).

Any advice on the best manner to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Riana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is inspired and based on [this Rowan Miller's presentation at TechEd 2014](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid=).

My main concern was to be able to filtered out "Posts" and "Comments" collections (according to a known conditions) when I load a Blog aggregate.

Lazy loading was not a good solution as it will send too much query to the database in order to load all needed posts and their corresponding comments (Posts and Comments collections can be huge)

I thought Eager loading, using "Include" operator, was not a good solution because "Include" operator do not support filter. That means that if I load my blogs like this : **myContext.Blogs.Include("Posts")**, Posts collection is not filtered and all the posts from the database will be loaded, I don't want that.

In EF6, it is now possible to intercept and modify queries before it is interepreted to SQL and sent to the database. This feature is the key solution.

My solution is to intercept all SELECT queries on the Post and Comment objects and modify them to apply my filters. With this implementation, I can do eager loading and still all the SELECT queries on Post and Comment object have filters applied automatically.

Rowan Miller demonstrate this feature by implementing a Soft delete.

Hope this help,

Riana